How to remove ControlNet stderr message "Some weights of the model checkpoint at openai/clip..."
I ran the following code.
controlnet='ControlNetPath'

import sys;
sys.path.append(controlnet)

from omegaconf import OmegaConf
from IPython.utils import io
from ldm.util import instantiate_from_config
config = OmegaConf.load(f"{controlnet}/models/cldm_v15.yaml")
with io.capture_output(stderr=False) as captured:
  model = instantiate_from_config(config.model)

Then I got the following message. (I omit it since it is too long.)
Some weights of the model checkpoint at openai/clip-vit-large-patch14 were not used when initializing CLIPTextModel: ['vision_model.encoder...

The code works fine, and I can ignore the message. However, I want to remove it because it clutters the logs.
What is the problem? How can I remove or suppress this message?
